# laravel notifciation inserting with wrong table columns

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-5.7

**Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `data`, `read_at`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)**

Where I has migration and table like this:

```
Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('type');
    $table->morphs('notifiable');
    $table->text('data');
    $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I dont have user_id and look the notifications(id,type,data).. its completely different.

My `NotificationClass`

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail', 'database'];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        "message" => "this is a test",
        "url" => "go somewhere else",
    ];
}
```

no idea what is affecting the insertion.

Comment: you need to provide a user to notify for, how do you use the notification? facade? notify method? trait?

Comment: I used `$user-notify(new NotificationClass)`

Comment: @ReyYoung Please provide your controller logic where you have used `$user->notify()`

Comment: i dont have anything in my controller i just called the notify method given by the notifiable trait

Comment: @ReyYoung But where you have called the notify method? I mean which file?

Comment: I have just did this in my controller.
`
$user = User::find(1);
$user->notify(new NotificationClass());
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the user_id column to the notifications table. This way, the notification knows the user it is assigned to. Without this column, a notification can't be assigned to a user.